# How should I make rounded NSBox with blurred background?

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-animation, appkit

Is there a way that I can make a transparent and rounded NSBox with a blurred background?

I have tried to use CA Background Filters to achieve this, but it seems that the part of the background which is blurred is not rounded, as you can see here: [image: rounded NSBox with rectangular blurred background]

Is there a way that I can somehow prevent the blurred background from overflowing the border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally fix this by wrapping my `NSBox` with an `NSView` that had a cornerRadius property, and then applying the CA filter to that `NSView`.